# Why do Visual Studio updates take significantly longer to install than Visual Studio itself?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

Recently I had the experience of installing Visual Studio 2012 and 2013 and installing their respective Update 4's.

In both instances, the base Visual Studio install takes much less time(at least half as much) than the Update 4's.

This really confuses me because firstly the Update 4's are much smaller than the base Visual Studio.

Secondly it is my intuitive understanding that by definition an update should just be a patch, which should not take longer than the actual software itself.

In both cases when installing the updates, I noticed the installer wastes a lot of time "saving restore points", are these restore points the culprits?

Comment: 1) You'd have to ask Microsoft that question. Frequently, files are in use by other processes and there's a wait time while they close/exit, backup files are created. Many other things could cause it to take longer.  2) No, an update isn't necessarily just a patch. In many cases, it replaces entire portions of an application and all it's files. 3) Restore points are what are used to keep your system in working order in case something in the update crashes. Windows can then revert to that *restore point* to revert the changes. See the WIndows help file for more info; they're part of the OS.

Comment: Addition to #1 in my last comment: Also, the update has to take time to check file versions and date/time stamps in order to determine what needs to be updated, what features you've installed, and do many more things that the original install doesn't have to do. It also has to try to preserve your existing settings and configuration, which the original install didn't.

Comment: Thanks Ken. However, in the case of Warcraft 3 computer game, updates are really small and fast. That's what gave me the impression all updates should be fast.

Comment: Using a single game update speed as a judgement for how everything works is simply foolish. It's like trying to judge the average speed of all automobiles by driving a single car. Just because you happened to drive a Porsche doesn't mean that a Toyota Prius or Hyundai Sonata will be as fast. Unless you're willing to try to use Warcraft 3 as the only software on your computer, use some common sense - software is very rarely one-size-fits-all, and because one does something does not mean all do exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

Great question.  As you note, installing an update is just installing the differences, so you might think that it would go quicker than a new "greenfield" install.

First, it's important to remember that these updates are *huge*.  We release them roughly every three months, so this contains the bug fixes and new feature work that we were able to sneak into the update.  So while the patch does just contain the different DLLs, a one-line change will require a whole new DLL.  If some internal method's signature changed, now all the callers have to change.  You can see how it's easy for a one-liner to be a several hundred kilobyte patch quite quickly.

(Our patches include a full copy of the new binaries, not a patch that takes the old binary and changes only the few(?) changed bytes.)

Second, the update install process is *crazy* about trying to keep your update installation from wrecking your install.  (So that either the update succeeded or it can rollback to the last known good state.)  This means, for example, that before writing down the new DLL, the update will verify that your existing install is in a good state.  In contrast, installing a new version of VS is just writing the data and needs no verification.  This is minor, admittedly, but does adds up.

Also, as you note, the restore point creation is somewhat expensive.  Again, the goal is to get you updated *or* to get you back to where you were before and avoid some wacky half-installed state where VS doesn't work, you can't complete your upgrade *or* downgrade.

That's the sort of scenario that we have nightmares about (at the end of a release, sometimes literally.)

Comment: so does this mean if I'm setting up a new dev machine and want vs2013 with update 4, I shouldn't bother installing base and update separately, but rather install both base and the update in one fell swoop from the vs2013.4 ISO just to save time? because there's nothing to wreck so i should bypass the safety rollback mechanisms of the update installer

Comment: @igbgotiz If you can do a VS 2013 Update 4 slipstream install, yes, that would alleviate this problem.  This is something that we do occasionally, but not always; I don't know if there are slipstream updates available (that include both the base VS 2013 as well as Update 4).